# How to make a share able link in laravel to public

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i have a laravel project where you can enter only using email and password this project create customer invoices and sometimes admin wants to share invoice using wtsapp and email how we can create link that can be public without email and password?
here is blade code example

```
<thead>
    <tr  class="header" id="myHeader">
        <th style="width: 20px">#</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Sub Total</th>
        <th>Recieved</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Advance</th>
        @if(Auth::user()->role < 3)
            <th>A Benefit</th>
            <th>Actual Ben</th>
        @endif
        <th>C Benefit</th>
        <th>S Price</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

@if ( $invoice->received_amount < $invoice->subtotal  )
    <td style="color: red" data-changein="subtotal">{{ $invoice->amount }}</td>
@elseif ( $invoice->received_amount > $invoice->subtotal && $invoice->amount_left > 0  )
    <td style="color: #CC9A2E" data-changein="subtotal">{{ $invoice->amount }}</td>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the invoice route from your route group which has `auth` middleware and that should work.

Your route could be like `yourapp.com/invoice/{invoice_id}`. The only issue with this is anyone could read the content of invoice if they know the invoice id. Things could get worse if you are using increment id. You might want to consider using a `hashed_id` column to prevent this from happening.